# How to render CGI in Blender using RTX cores & Optix

Tags: google-compute-engine

Whether it's with the T4 or the P100 GPU'S on google cloud, once I install Blender and go to system settings, the software doesn't detect any RTX cores in the Optix tab..

I tried with both the pre-built NVidia workstation settings and from scratch when creating various instances.

Do you know how to properly setup an RTX workstation for rendering images faster using Blender?

Whether that's with an other company, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [medium post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/leveraging-google-compute-engine-for-low-cost-gpu-rendering-and-other-fun-exercises-in-patience-bf621cd6b0ae), I don't know which OS you are using but I think this is a good start point. Let me know if it works for you or you have any issues.

Comment: Hey I'm trying to run it on Windows Server 2019.. 

Now it's not even letting me load Blender.. It says that OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required.

I installed the latest Nvidia Drivers successfully & see the Tesla P100s in Device Manager.

Any ideas for this issue? I won't be going after RTX Optix this time around, but something changed because now Blender won't even open..

Comment: Can you please share with me the Blender version you are using?